# Chain rule in Partial derivatives Proof

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, infinitesimals

I am trying to prove chain rule for Partial derivatives:

Let $z=f(x,y)$ and $x=x(t),y(t)$. We need to prove that:
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$$

Assuming $z$ is differentiable function we have the increment formula as:
$$\Delta z=f_x\Delta x+f_y \Delta y+\epsilon_1 \Delta x+\epsilon_2 \Delta y$$

Where $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 \to 0$ as $(\Delta x,\Delta y) \to (0,0)$

Now we have:
$$\frac{\Delta z}{\Delta t}=f_{x} \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}+f_{y} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta t}+\varepsilon_{1} \frac{\Delta_{x}}{\Delta t}+\varepsilon_{2} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta t}$$

Taking $\Delta t \to 0$ we get:
$$\lim _{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta z}{\Delta t}=f_{x} \lim _{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}+f_{y} \lim _{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta t}+\varepsilon_{1} \lim _{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}+\varepsilon_{2} \lim _{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta t}$$

Any way to prove from here?

Comment: If $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$, then you should be writing $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$, $\dfrac{dy}{dt}$, not $\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}$, etc. You have the derivation from what you've written. Just take the limit as $\Delta t \to 0$. What happens?

Comment: But can we say $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2 \to 0$ as $\Delta t \to 0$?

Comment: Well, as $\Delta t\to 0$, does $\Delta x\to 0$? And $\Delta y$?

Comment: That is what i am confused...Will it be true that as $\Delta t \to 0$, so is $\Delta x $ and $\Delta y$

Comment: Do you know any theorem relating differentiability and continuity?

Comment: Every differentiable function is continuous. Not sure which one you are talking about. Could you please explain?

Comment: That’s it. Think what it means.

Comment: I am not able to think, is it possible for you to explain?

Comment: Continuity of $x$ at $t=t_0$ means precisely that $x(t_0+\Delta t)\to x(t_0)$ as $\Delta t\to 0$.